# React Redux Invalid Prop supplied

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

My current flow of data is like this,

```
BookContainer (Passes in props needed by book form, eg drop down selection options)
|_ BookModal (Handles the form submission)
   |_ CreateBookForm (Contains form tag and input fields, Dumb Component)
```

The problem I'm facing is when my BookModal handles the form submission, everything goes through nicely however I get this error `this.props.books.map is not a function`. The books prop is passed in from the `BookContainer -> BookModal -> CreateBookForm` to populate the books I have to choose from. The return response from `BookModal` after the form submission from `CreateBookForm` is a Promise of whether the request is successful or failed.

I am not sure if my current flow of passing data is correct, but so far all the data displays correctly. It is only after when I submit the form I'll get this error.
I am using https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example as my boilerplate.
Any suggestions, or ideas is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: If a browser says it's not a function - it's not a function. Hence a suggestion: either don't invoke it or pass a proper array (or something that has a `.map()` method).

Comment: The problem is, when I do the form submission, the props is already there beforehand. And I just want the props to stay the same and not getting any new props after the form submission. However it seems like it's asking for new props after every form submission.

Comment: Nothing is "asking" anything - it's the "push" there not "pull". So it's the parent component that does not pass the required properties.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really get what you mean by the parent component that does not pass the required properties? My parent component has already passed the required properties which is required for the form to render properly. The form is rendered correctly.

Comment: And on the second time it does not pass the properties. Hence the child component does not get an array

Comment: Is it possible to just use the properties which was initially loaded and ignore the second time?

Comment: Nope. The whole idea of react that there is no "previous time" - you every time render everything from scratch.

Comment: Ah, I finally found my mistake after you pointing out that react is based on current state. The mistake I made was in my action creators, I had been using the wrong case which kept changing the state which was not suppose to change and hence causing the wrong property type. Everything looks well now, thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the mistake is just a state used by 2 different properties. Hence causing the different property types. All I had to do was modify my action creator and not mix up the states.